# Remove checkbox from excel sheet cascading each other

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge excel sheet but instead of having one checkbox in a cell, there are many checkboxes on top of each other, what would be the VB Code that only one check box remains and rest all others are deleted?

Comment: Yes, you can... Did you try it? Are the check boxes in discussion `activeX` type, of `Form`?

Comment: I wasn't able to come up with the right logic, the remaining checkbox shall retain it's original value, these are form checkboxes

Comment: Should I understand that all of the ones staying on top o the other **on the same cell** **have the same value**? Otherwise, based on what to except from deletion the one **you want**?

Comment: that is correct. the ones staying on top of the other on the same cell have the same value.

Comment: Then, you can try the next scenario: Iterate between all shapes in the respective sheet, check if they are `Form` check boxes and place in a `Dictionary` their `TopLeftCell.address` (as key), excepting the one when the dictionary key is created and place the other shapes (to be deleted) name in an array. Then iterate between the array elements and delete them. Is it a scenario you could understand?

Comment: i guess i will struggle with it's implementation, can you please help me with the code too? would be much appreciated.

Comment: I will try creating a piece of code, not immediately because am rather busy, but before that I would like asking you: Do you understand what `TopLeftCell.address` of a shape means?

Comment: i guess it means the cell address where the checkbox is in?,

Comment: let me try to do it too but i guess i would most likely fail as i have never worked with VB before, if im successful I'll post it here.
Extremely grateful for the assistance & help you are offering !

Comment: Rather correct... I mean, as it say, the cell where the shape top left corner is situated... I will prepare an answer now. Not longer then 5 minutes, I hope... I cannot handle a `Dictionary`, it needs a reference, or to know about it what does, in order to use it without a reference (Early binding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It uses a dictionary to keep unique shapes **to remain** top cell addresses and all overlapping ones name will be placed in an array, which finally will be used to delete them:

```
Sub deleteDuplicateChkBOnTheSameCell()
    Dim chkB As MSForms.CheckBox, s As Shape, sh As Worksheet
    Dim arrDel, kS As Long, El, dict As Object
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    ReDim arrDel(sh.Shapes.count) 'redim the array for maximum number of elemnts to be loaded
    
    'Place all check boxes TopLeftCell addres in a dictionary:
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each s In sh.Shapes
        If TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" Then 'Form CheckBox object...
            If Not dict.Exists(s.TopLeftCell.Address) Then
                dict.Add s.TopLeftCell.Address, vbNullString  'place the first found
            Else
                arrDel(kS) = s.name: kS = kS + 1                         'next occurrences loaded in the array
            End If
        End If
    Next s
    
    If kS > 0 Then 'check if the code really found duplicates...
        ReDim Preserve arrDel(kS - 1)  'keep in the array only loaded elements
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         For Each El In arrDel                  'iterate between the shapes to be deleted name and do the job:
            sh.Shapes(El).Delete
         Next El
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, check it and send some feedback.

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: Working, Extremely Grateful for this beautiful code !

Comment: @Jitesh Ochani It would be better when place the next question to be able to prove that you did something by your own. Anything...